# How to fix issue : Untity Sphere Collider Change the Orientation of GameObject?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

In my Unity project, I create a 3D fish that is positioned upright correctly. When I put a sphere collider around the fish, everything looks good in Unity Editor. But, after I build, install, and run the APK on my phone, the fish is rotated about 80 degree in the X, and Y axis.

I am using Unity 2017.4.3.f1.

I've searched around the web but can't find any answer. I would greatly appreciate if anyone can help me out or give me a suggestion on how to fix this issue.

---

PS: Please read my comment below for the solution to my issue. Thanks.

Comment: I just found out that the issue was caused by some software bugs in the code that randomly rotated the fish. I've just fixed the issue now. I want to close this question, but it has been answered by someone else. Therefore, unfortunately, stackoverflow does not allow me to close this question in this case.

Comment: Can't you write an answer yourself, and then accept it as the soluction...?

Comment: @Steen:  I think the user "Zohaib Zaidi" gave me a good suggestion upon which I was able to debug further and solve the issue. So, I have to give him the credit and pick his answer.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can see is if on starting is your fish colliding with something. Do a Debug.Log on your OnCollisionEnter and see what you get.

Use adb.exe logcat -s Unity in command prompt with your Android Phone connected to your system to get Unity logs.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just find out where the bug is. The fish is randomly rotated due to some bugs. I just fix it now. :-)